# Fixed Position Menu modification guidance

Tags: javascript, css, menu, show-hide

Found a simple stick nav that puts the small menu on the left side of the browser window. No problem so far but I am unsure how to turn that into a sliding menu that reduces to an icon like you would see on a website template theme color switcher. {edit - I have been searching google but am not using the correct terms I think. Appreciate any suggestions as to what I am looking for so as to solve this and learn.}

Something like this quick sketch in Photoshop.
[image]

The fiddle is: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/wLzrp1nr/1/)

and the code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
  #menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 8em;
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: white;
    color: #4E4E4E;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: left;
    border: #4e4e4e;
    border-left: none;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px black;

  }
  #menu li { margin: 0 }
  #menu a { color: inherit }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul id=menu>
<li><a href="#L384">Section 1</a>
<li><a href="#details">Section 2</a>
<li><a href="#FAQ">Section 3</a>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any javascript in your question.  If you have made an attempt using javascript to accomplish your goal, please post what you have.  If you have not, please refer to the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help topic and revise your question.  SO is for helping developers with specific issues in their code.  It is not a free coding service.

Comment: I appreciate your honest and forthright response to my question but perhaps you read something in there that was, in fact, not in there. I am fairly certain there was no request for "free coding services" but thank you for explaining that anyway.

Re-reading my post, I realize that I should have very explicitly requested guidance in a specific direction so that I could solve my own problem and will revise to add this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to add to your menu a "square" with pseudoelement `:after` positioned where you want like this:

```
 #menu:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: -40px;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px black;
   display: block;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
  #menu:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   z-index:1;
   top: 1px;
   right: -1px;
   height: 39px;
   width: 4px;
   display: block;
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

The `before` is just a white box to cover the shadow of the `after`so it will look joined to the menú,

Then position the menu outside the window just showing the `after` element and make an event on click to add a class to the menu to "show" or "hide".

```js
$('#menu').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
 #menu {
   position: fixed;
   left: -198px;
   top: 50%;
   width: 8em;
   margin: -2.5em 0 0 0;
   z-index: 5;
   background: white;
   color: #4E4E4E;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: large;
   text-align: left;
   border: #4e4e4e;
   border-left: none;
   padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2.5em;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px black;
   transition: left 0.2s linear;
 }
 
 #menu li {
   margin: 0
 }
 
 #menu a {
   color: inherit
 }
 
 #menu:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: -40px;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px black;
   display: block;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
  #menu:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   z-index:1;
   top: 1px;
   right: -1px;
   height: 39px;
   width: 4px;
   display: block;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
 .visible {
   left:0 !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=menu>
  <li><a href="#L384">Section 1</a>
    <li><a href="#details">Section 2</a>
      <li><a href="#FAQ">Section 3</a>
</ul>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/wLzrp1nr/2/)**

Comment: Ah! using the after element was the clue I was looking for, thank you. I was having trouble phrasing my google search properly so I kept finding answers that had nothing to do with what I needed.

Comment: Is there an "industry" name for this type of mini menu? Fixed menu usually shows top and bottom types and floating brings up a thousand css float tutorials. lol

Comment: There may be some "industry" names for these menus but I can't help you there, probably some libraries with jqueryui, bootstrap, and many similar ones may have these type of custom menu but since I get paid to make my own designs /codes I close to never use them.

Comment: Well, thank you again. More that I could have asked for but it fit the bill. Now I'm having fun modifying and playing with it. Going to find your answer very useful and fun to experiment with.